# How to keep a widget output dynamic in a cached page (with W3 total cache)

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

Im trying to output a set of random posts using the following widget call in Wordpress.
The time is updated each time the code executes but the widget contents are always the same.

```
    <!--mfunc echo 'real time = '.date('H i s',time()); -->
    <?php echo 'real time = '.date('H i s',time()); ?>
    <?php
        genesis_widget_area( 'home-right', array(
            'before' => '<div class="home-right widget-area grid-zr-12 grid-md-4">',
            'after' => '</div>'
        ));
    ?>
    <!--/mfunc-->
```

Is there a way to also make the widget output dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fragment caching in W3TC you need to include the `W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY` constant which was added for security purposes, and you should not be using `<?php>` tags within `<!--mfunc--><!--/mfunc-->`. You also need to make sure that you are using `Page Caching` type `Disk:Basic` and `Late Initialization` (on the page caching settings) -

> *Enables support for WordPress functionality in fragment caching for the page caching engine. Use of this feature may increase response times.*

In `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY', md5( rand( 0, 999999 ) ) ); // random "secret"
```

In your template:

```
<!--mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
echo 'real time = '.date( 'H i s', time() );
genesis_widget_area( 'home-right', array(
    'before' => '<div class="home-right widget-area grid-zr-12 grid-md-4">',
    'after' => '</div>'
) );
<!--/mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working with minify enabled, once disabled I got it working!

Comment: i dont know if this work yet, but this is the most complete answer I've seen so far. So thank you for that

Comment: add mfunc into Ignored comment stems (minify setting), so you can get this working with minify enabled.